# Removing array components that are outside given limit

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

In matlab I have calculated an array representing a stress field of an elliptic cross-section. That I have done by

```
% Input
a = 4; b = 2; M = 5;
K = pi*a^3*b^3/(a^2+b^2);

% Stress function
y = linspace(-a,a);
z = linspace(-b,b);
[Y,Z] = meshgrid(y,z);
X = 2*M/K*(a^4*Z.^2+b^4*Y.^2)^(1/2)/(a^2+b^2);
```

At the same time I have an ellipsis defined as

```
t = -pi:0.01:pi;
YEllipsis = a*cos(t);
ZEllipsis = b*sin(t);
```

I need to remove all components of the array X that lies outside the border of the ellipsis defined above. My aim is to plot the contour of the ellipsis by lines, and plot the stress field (X) with contour lines in the same plot.

Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn about logical indexing.  Here's an [article](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) that should get you going.

And here's the code to set all the values of X to zero that lie outside the ellipse.  (I assume that's what you mean by "remove all components of the array X that lie outside the border", that is the typical way this is done.)

```
 X(y.^2/a^2 + z.^2/b^2 < 1) = 0;
```

Or, if you really just want that array, you can do it this way:

```
XNew = X(y.^2/a^2 + z.^2/b^2 < 1);
```